# Resize raster for dimensions to match extent

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a list of Raster Objects, with different extents and dimensions (columns/rows), namely (0, 1400, 0, 2000) and (500,350). The resolution is 4 (dimensions * resolution equals extent). The data values in each raster are either NA or 1.

I would like to index in the object, but using its extent, and not dimensions (so index in the range 0-2000 instead of 0-500). So, I would like to change the raster dimensions to match the extent of the object. Adjusting the resolution does not seem to apply in this case.

I tried to use resample function after creating a new raster with the appropriate dimensions, but after resampling the new raster had correct dimensions but the extent and values (all NA) were messed up. I suppose the solution might be adjusting this approach

```
ref
a <- raster(nrow = ymax(ref), ncol = xmax(ref))
a <- resample(ref,a)
```

If the raster was 500x350 pixels before, I would like it to be 2000x1400. So I would guess that where 1 pixel was, there will be 4. And I would like those 4 pixels to all have the same value as the one before.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

I have attached an example raster: https://ucarecdn.com/7cc71657-c829-4a3c-b522-7024b7996efe/

Comment: Your question if hard to follow. Can you rewrite it and include example data generated by code (`raster(  )`). Perhaps you are looking for `aggregate` or `disaggregate` or `extent<-`, or....

Comment: I added some parts in order to simplify what I would like to do, and removed unnecessary stuff. I think I have included example data with the final link; if not, I do not know any other way to attach files to a question in this platform.

Comment: disaggregate did the trick!

Comment: FYI- Data can often be added to a question by executing something like `dput(ref)` and then copy-pasting the console output into the question.